# Importing mysql table in excel

Tags: python, mysql, excel, fetchall

I am noob in python but I need to export MySQL table into .xls file using xlwt in python. I succeeded in exporting the table using example from here

http://ryrobes.com/featured-articles/using-xlwt-and-python-to-export-an-oracle-dataset-to-excel-python-simple-etl-part-2/

but the order of table column in excel and MySQL does not match if there are more than two columns in MySQL table.

Here's a part of the code:

```
from xlwt import *
import sys
import MySQLdb

table_name='student'
sql_select="SELECT * FROM %s"%table_name
conn1 =MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='',db='test')
cu_select=conn1.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
try:
        cu_select.execute(sql_select)
except MySQLdb.Error, e:
        errInsertSql = "Insert Sql ERROR!! sql is==>%s" %(sql_select)
        sys.exit(errInsertSql)

result_set = cu_select.fetchall()'
```

I tried printing result_set and found that mismatch starts from here. Can anyone help me.

Comment: The reason this is happening is because dictionaries have random order. Since your requirements are relatively straightforward you can use a normal cursor, i.e. not a DictCursor.

Comment: @bernie Thanks, the order is now matched but I can't get column name.

Comment: Column metadata can be taken from `cursor.description`

Comment: Thanks! the problem is now solved.

Answer (score 1):

Tables are organized alphabetically or by by ascending order ,if you want organised order use rows instead .

Comment: this will also solve the order problem but even using rows I can't seem to get column name.